# How to filter in sub collection's documents (firebase)?

Tags: firebase

My problem is that I use wrong query to get the date.

```
          const SaveDateBase = async ( e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
           

                await setDoc(doc(db, "Users", "Pompy", "Pompy", user.uid), {
                  displayName: user.displayName,
                  uid:  user?.uid,
                  modulyPV}).then(()=>{
                 console.log("moduly", modulyPV)
                  })
        
         
        
          };
        

              useEffect(() => {
                const getUsers = async (users) => {
                  const URC = query(collection(db, "Users").document("Pompy").collection("Pompy"), where("uid", "==", user?.uid));

                
        const data = await getDocs(URC)
        setModulyPV(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
                }
                getUsers();
              },[])
```

The date are saved in date base, and I can successfully update/delete them, but I do something wrong to fetch (read?) them.
I guess is problem with the code.

Comment: Which field is a date field? Which is exactly the error?

Comment: TypeError: (0,firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.collection)(_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db, "Users").document is not a function. (In '(0,firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.collection)(_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db, "Users").document("Pompy")', '(0,firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.collection)(_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db, "Users").document' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in diff ways, first "Pompy" seems to be your document where you are storing a nested collection then you document "Pompy" So for retrieve that specific document should be something like:

```
let snapshot = await db
.collection('Users')
.doc('Pompy')
.collection('Pompy')
.get()

snapshot.forEach(doc =>{
  console.log('data:', doc.data())
})
```

Then to query into the nested collection would be something like querying the nested collections.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-get-sub-collections?hl=es-419#firestore_data_get_sub_collections-nodejs

You can also use collection groups.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

```
const pompys = query(collectionGroup(db, 'Pompy'), where("uid", "==", user?.uid));
```

Comment: I cannot make a console log, I just get the error or another one - collection cannot have 3 segments (users/pompy/pompy).

Comment: I edited it try that way